# JavaScript redirect based on presence of cookie

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a system where a cookie is created when ever a user lands on a specific page.

for example:
if a user goes to .com/jp/a3 a cookie is created.

I am using this code to create the cookie and it seems to be creating the cookie on that page.

```
<script>
  document.cookie = "name_of_cookie=a3; expires=31 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"
</script>
```

I currently have pages .com/jp/a1 through .com/jp/a3 created. So there is a possibility of three cookies being created.

Upon the user's next visit, I would like the browser to check for these cookies and redirect back to that page when a user visits the normal landing page. If a user has been to multiple pages, I would like the priority to be set to the page they visited first. (this may involve coding some if else statements into my javascript to set the cookie I assume?) If this is difficult, I would be ok with just moving through the a1-a3 list as a1 having the highest priority and a3 the lowest.

I have tried adding the following code to my website.com/index.html file but am not having any luck.

```
<script>
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = name_of_cookie + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var redirect = getCookie("name_of_cookie");
    if (redirect != "") {
        window.location = "http://www.website.com/jp/" + redirect;
    } else {
       window.location = "http://www.website.com/" 
    }
  }

  checkCookie();
</script>
```

One issue I think I may be facing, is that while I am on the a3.com pages, I am able to see the cookie in my storage, however, when I go to my index.html page, I am not able to see the cookie in my storage. 
I have set the path to /, will this only make the cookie available in the .com/jp/ subfolder, or should it be accessible on the .com/index.html page?

Thank you in advance for any assistance anyone could provide.

Comment: ***"I have tried adding the following code to my website.com/index.html"*** - is your server configured to run `php`inside `html`?

Comment: That is a very good question. and I am not positive about that. Maybe it is best to stick to Javascript. :)

Comment: Either change index.html extension to .php or use JavaScript for the redirection. You can read the cookies on client side too: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @Ion Bazan Thank you that page was very helpful! I'm still having some issues, but I feel I am making progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the getCookie function defined wrong. when testing it, I got the error `name_of_cookie is not defined`. It seems that on the first line of your `getCookie()` function, you used `name_of_cookie` instead of `cname` as you defined the parameter `getCookie(cname)`

All you have to do is change it to

```
var name = cname + "=";
```

Also, by specifying the path as `/` you should be able to see the cookies from your index too.

Comment: Hello @Abraham Murciano Benzadon  Thank you for the help! I have taken some advice of earlier comments and tried giving a go at creating javascript that will do this instead. but still not quite there :) I updated my question with the new java script. I did try your suggestion of renaming to .php but still didn't seem to have any luck.

Comment: I see the new JavaScript, but I don't see why it's not working.. Have you defined the getCookie() function, it is not a native JavaScript function.
Also, you have defined the checkCookie function, but you've not run it. you have to run it with `checkCookie();`
If any of these things work, let me know and ill update the answer

Comment: Hello @Abraham Murciano Benzadon I have added the complete function with the getCookie() function included, and checkCookie(); being called at the end, but it still doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: Now that I can see your getCookie function, I updated the answer. I believe this is where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake!

I forgot quotations around name_of_cookie in the second line.

Corrected answer is:

```
<script>
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = "name_of_cookie" + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var redirect = getCookie("name_of_cookie");
    if (redirect != "") {
        window.location = "http://www.website.com/jp/" + redirect;
    } else {
       window.location = "http://www.website.com/" 
    }
  }

  checkCookie();
</script>
```

Thanks for the assistance everyone!